# Do we really need the constraint qualification?

Tags: optimization, fake-proofs, karush-kuhn-tucker

I can't keep my fingers off Nocedal/Wright's *Numerical Optimization* (1999,1E) and I apologize. But maybe YOU can shed light on the question:

*Why does a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ need to satisfy the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) **AND** the stationarity of the Lagrange equation to qualify as a prospective local solution to a static constrained optimization problem?*

Or, to put it in other words,

*Do we really need the LICQ for a first-order necessary optimality condition?*

What's wrong with the following conclusion from the set of implications that I collected (all references taken from the book given above)?

1. There are Lagrange multipliers s.t. the Lagrange is stationary at $x$. $\stackrel{12.4}{\Leftrightarrow}$ Any element $\varphi$ in $F_1$ satisfies $(\nabla f)^T\varphi \ge 0$.
2. $d$ is a limiting direction. $\stackrel{12.3.i}{\implies}$ $d \in F_1$
3. $x$ is a local solution. $\stackrel{12.2}{\implies}$ For any limiting direction $d$, we have that $(\nabla f)^Td \ge 0$.

From (2) we have that the set of limiting directions is a subset of $F_1$. From (1) we have that the stationarity of the Lagrangian is equivalent to the non-negativity of $(\nabla f)^Td$ for any element of $F_1$.

According to (3) I'd say the necessary condition for $x$ being a solution is given by the stationarity of the Lagrangian alone, since the proofs of Lemma 12.4, Lemma 12.3.i and Theorem 12.2 do not depend on LICQ (if I got it correctly).

Thank you!

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example
$$ \min \quad x \quad \text{s.t.} \quad x^2 \le 0,\, x\in\mathbb R $$ 
shows that constraint qualifications are indeed necessary, as the Lagrangian isn't stationary at the optimum.

Comment: Write down the stationary condition for the Lagrangian and you will see that they are not satisfied.

Comment: One liners rarely make good Answers.  It's up to you as the one attempting an Answer to present a "curated" explanation of the ideas.  See the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for more about how to answer well.

Comment: I thought you might want to think about it yourself first. next time I will call it hints.

Comment: I'm not the OP of the Question.  I appreciate that you wish me to think about the Question for myself, and I will do so.  Hints, where not specifically requested by the OP, are best presented as Comments.

Comment: @user251257: Thank you four your answer (highly appreciated in times of tumbleweeds)! I followed your guide and found out, like you suggested, that for any multiplier $\lambda$ we have that $\nabla \mathcal{L}(x^*=0) \neq 0$ confirming your claim. But from this I conclude (see (1) above) that there is an element $w$ in $F_1$ s.t. $(\nabla f^*)^Tw < 0$. If this $w$ were a limiting direction (what we can't check from the above given criteria), the necessary condition in (3) would be false, dequalifying $x^*=0$ as a candidate for a local minimum. This is independent from the outcome of the LICQ.

Comment: I have the 2. ed. of Nocedal. So I not entirely follow the numbering and notation. If $F_1$ is the linearized tangent cone, then it is $\R$ here. The tangent cone is only $\{0\}$. Therefor the first order condition fails. Obviously there is no limiting direction $w$ such $\nabla f(x^*)^T w < 0$.

Comment: $F_1$ denotes the tangent cone to the feasible set at $x^*$. It is defined as the set of all positively scaled limiting directions $d$ satisfying $d^T\nabla c_i^* = 0$ for all equality constraints and $d^T \nabla c_i^* \ge 0$ for all active inequality constraints. Acc. to your example we have $\nabla c^* = -2x^* = 0$. Hence, $F_1 = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann That cone is called the *linearized* tangent cone. There is difference between $F_1$ and the tangent cone. This is also the reason for constraint qualifications.

Comment: Definition 12.4 simply defines $F_1$ to be a tangent cone. I'm fine with the full terminus being _linearized_ tangent cone. Does it affect my question? All I'm trying to find out really is if the stationarity of the Lagrangian _alone_ is a necessary condition for a point to be a local solution. And if not, why. What troubles me is that your example doesn't even seem to have the stationarity property. What about an example that satisfies $(\exists \lambda) \nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x^*) = 0$, that does not satisfy LICQ _and_ $x^*$ being not a solution. If I am right such a problem does not exist.

Comment: 1) $F_1$ is the tangent cone of  the *linearized* problem of original problem. $F_1$ as you stated here is in general not the tangent cone of the original problem. 2) For the example I stated, $F_1=\mathbb R$ and the tangent cone is $\{0\}$, as the only feasible point is $0$. 3) This affect your question, as the example shows stationary of the Lagrangian along is not necessary for a minimum. 4) There are other constraint qualifications, strictly weaker than LICQ. See regularity conditions (or constraint qualifications) under  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions

Comment: Though I'm still in question what's wrong with my argumentation I thank you for the fruitful discussion and your answer! I must admit that I agree with @hardmath: You pinpointed the question but it was bit a short for my level of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

(Since my edit proposal was rejected and further comments were discouraged, please consider my following extension to user251257's answer)

**Some remarks to the answer from the author of the question:**

My claim was that the stationarity of the Lagrangian *alone* is the necessary condition for a point to be a local solution of the optimization problem:

$$x^* \text{ is a local solution} \implies (\exists \lambda) \: \nabla \mathcal{L}(x^*) = 0,$$

which is equivalent to

$$ (\forall \lambda) \nabla \mathcal{L}(x^*) \neq 0 \implies x^* \text{ is not a local solution}. $$

Now user251257 has given an example that shows

$$ (\forall \lambda) \nabla \mathcal{L}(x^*) \neq 0 \wedge x^* \text{ is a local solution}, $$

which is the exact negation of the above given (claimed) implication.

Comment: Duh, I can contact you here! Max at some point can you pop here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29374/game-tech-internals got some stuff to discuss.